# Not able to obtain struct item

Tags: c, struct, kernel

Given, in the function called,

```
void callFunct1 (arg_t **q) {
  if (t==1) // 
   *q = NULL;
  else
   memcpy((*q)->items, listOfContents, size of listOfContents); // listOfContents is const static, no memcpy required
};
EXPORT_SYMBOL(callFunct1);
```

Given t == 0

How may I ensure that the memcpy is getting the contents?

```
arg_t* q; 
                                        //
callFunct1 (&q);
    //not able to obtain from here (q->items)
```

arg_t is just a struct.

```
typedef struct {
  list items[100];
} arg_t;

typedef struct {
  int contents;
} list;
```

Comment: `typedef struct {
  struct item;
} arg_t;
` is not valid code. Can you put the actual code? Also, how do you know `memcpy` is not getting called? Did you try putting a `printk` next to it and checking the kernel logs to see if it works?

Comment: updated.

 
it was printing before when I did not use callFunct1 (arg_t *q) instead of callFunct1 (arg_t **q) . However, I have to return a NULL, and it works for returning a NULL. Thank you, Shahbaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. since for the q memory is not allocated so you need to allocate the memory first forr 
   the q and then copy the contents to q.

   To the memcpy address of the structure should be passed &((*q)->items) and similarly 
   for source structure

   (OR)
2. change the function to callFunct1 (arg_t *q) and can be called as below

   arg_t q;
   callFunct1 (&q);

Comment: 1. malloc before the call or within the call? isn't q pointing to a const static (listOfContents), hence no memcpy required?
2. if i change it to *q, it won't return null when t == 1.

Comment: added 

q = kmalloc(size of(arg_t), GFP_KERNEL);
before
callFunct1 (&q);